# Функция тангенса

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Если верить калькулятору, то tan(53.13) = 1.3333
Однако python втирает мне что `tan(53.13)` = -0.28439023721952283

```
>>> from math import tan
>>> tan(53.13)
-0.28439023721952283
```

В чем дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tan(53.13 градусов) = 1.3333
tan(53.13 радиан) = -0.28439023721952283
```

Аргумент тангенса в *Python* (да и не только в *Python*) исчисляется в радианах.

Для преобразования между радианами и градусами в *Python* в модуле `math` есть две функции:

- `degrees(x)` переводит угол `x` из радианов в градусы;
- `radians(x)` переводит угол `x` из градусов в радианы.

Comment: Можно ли его исчислять в градусах?

Comment: @Sithell Нет. Используйте функции перевода.

Comment: её писать самому? или же есть встроенная?

Comment: @Sithell Есть встроенная. Посмотрите внимательнее на ответ.